# How do I properly tell Microtype that `newcomputermodern` is the same as `computer modern`?

Tags: microtype, newcomputermodern

I noticed this error message from `microtype` in my log file:

```
Package microtype Info: Loading generic protrusion settings for font family
(microtype)             `NewCM10-Book.otf' (encoding: TU).
(microtype)             For optimal results, create family-specific settings.
(microtype)             See the microtype manual for details.
```

Well, I figured, there should be SOME way of telling Microtype that NewComputerModern is PRETTY much the same as Computer Modern, right?

And I found it; table on pg 21 of the manual, it ha a table that even says that Latin Modern Roman has custom font settings, and says "Alias: New Computer Modern". However, no matter if I load with `\usepackage{newcomputermodern}` or `\usepackage[regular]{newcomputermodern}` it lists the above error (just with `NewCM10-Regular.otf` instead of `NewCM10-Book.otf`.

Alright, that is fine, the manual suggests using `\DeclareMicrotypeAlias{lmr}{cmr}` so I created the following MNWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[]{newcomputermodern}
\usepackage{microtype}
%\DeclareMicrotypeAlias{NewCM10-Regular.otf}{cmr}
\DeclareMicrotypeAlias{NewCM10-Book.otf}{cmr}

\begin{document}
Test text
\end{document}
```

But I still get the following error:

```
(d:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/microtype/mt-cmr.cfg
File: mt-cmr.cfg 2013/05/19 v2.2 microtype config. file: Computer Modern Roman (
RS)
)
Package microtype Info: Loading generic protrusion settings for font family
(microtype)             `NewCM10-Book.otf' (encoding: TU).
(microtype)             For optimal results, create family-specific settings.
(microtype)             See the microtype manual for details.
 [1

{d:/texlive/2020/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}] (./MWE.aux))
```

Which shows that the command I added is doing SOMETHING, but I'm still getting that error. Can anyone tell me what I am doing incorrectly? I assumed that the name it gives in the error message would be the correct name to tell it to use Computer Modern's settings for, but if that is wrong, how do I find the real name to use?

Comment: While it's possible to load `mt-cmr.cfg`, the warning you get about protrusion is the same. Better by loading `mt-LatinModernRoman.cfg`, but a warning about a missing slot `f_f` appears.

Comment: @egreg Wait, does it have separate Latin Modern and Computer Modern defaults? It says that it uses `\DeclareMicrotypeAlias{lmr}{cmr}` in the manual, should I take it that is out of date or just a confusing comment? Would the right alias command then be `\DeclareMicrotypeAlias{NewCM10-Book.otf}{lmr}`? I don't mind if *one* letter is missing some settings....

Comment: As far as I can see, `mt-cmr.cfg` is oriented to legacy encodings, whereas `mt-LatinModern.cfg` sets things up for TU, with a large character inheritance table.

Comment: There's already the line `\DeclareMicrotypeAlias{New Computer Modern}{Latin Modern Roman}` in `microtype.cfg`. However, I wasn't aware that `newcomputermodern.sty` loads the font by file name (`NewCM10-Book.otf`) rather than font name. I'll add that for the next version.

Comment: @Robert It has options for either `NewCM10-Book.otf` or `NewCM10-Regular.otf`

Comment: This has been fixed in the current version (v2.8a).

Answer (score 11):

It is possible to load a configuration file if you specify an NFSS family name.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{microtype}

\setmainfont{NewCM10}[
  NFSSFamily=NewCMRoman,
  Extension=.otf,
  Numbers=OldStyle,
  UprightFont=*-Book,
  ItalicFont=*-BookItalic,
  BoldFont=*-Bold,
  BoldItalicFont=*-BoldItalic,
  SlantedFont=*-Book,
  SlantedFeatures={FakeSlant=0.25},
  BoldSlantedFont=*-Bold,
  BoldSlantedFeatures={FakeSlant=0.25},
  SmallCapsFeatures={Numbers=OldStyle},
]
\setmathfont{NewCMMath-Book.otf}

\DeclareMicrotypeAlias{NewCMRoman}{LatinModernRoman}

\begin{document}

\end{document}
```

The font loading commands are taken from the secondary package loaded by `newcomputermodern.sty`. However, this loses all other adjustments and commands defined there.

It would be good if the package author streamlines the font loading like in my code (his is quite confusing) and provides a family name. As it stands, `newcomputermodern.sty` is very rigid and allows for no option: take or leave.

Comment: I did not know about this issue. So If I add NFSSFamily=NewCMRoman, to newcomputermodern.sty that will be enough?

Comment: @Antonis Also the alias should be defined. You might test for `microtype` being loaded with `\AtBeginDocument`. I appreciate very much your work and promptness to solve all issues.

Comment: Just to make sure: (1) Add the line: NFSSFamily=NewCMRoman, (2) Add the line: \DeclareMicrotypeAlias{NewCMRoman}{LatinModernRoman}  (3) ?? what ?? And what if someone does not want to load microtype? Yes, I want NewCM to have the best possible support. Thanks.

Comment: @Antonis `\AtBeginDocument{\@ifpackageloaded{microtype}{\DeclareMicrotypeAlias{NewCMRoman}{LatinModernRoman}}{}}`

Comment: Great. I will do that soon.

Comment: and what about the Sans and Mono families? I guess Mono does not need that, but Sans should need it if available with LM. Are there microtype rules for LatinModernSans? And is it called "LatinModernSans". If yes I should add this alias too.

Comment: @Antonis My impression is that perhaps a full-fledged configuration file for NewCM would be a good addition, instead of relying on a similar one. Probably not a priority, though.

Comment: Maybe you are right. I will think about this. In the meantime do you understand what is this message I get when I use the alias:Package microtype Warning: Unknown slot number of character
(microtype)                `/f_f'
(microtype)                in font encoding `TU' in inheritance list
(microtype)                `mt-LatinModernRoman.cfg/105(protrusion)'.

Comment: @Antonis I guess this is one of the reasons why a proper configuration file is needed.